# Brunch mocha support gone?

Tags: mocha.js, brunch

I am looking into upgrading brunch to latest version of 1.7.1, but am running into trouble with my mocha tests not being run. Tracked this down to that "window.require('x_test')" at the end of test.js not being generated anymore. Tried renaming my test files from 'x_test.coffee' to 'x-test.coffee' (replacing underscore with dash), to no avail, as the docs indicate that suffix -test will be treated as test according to brunch conventions.

Any ideas?

Additional info: The support disappears between versions 1.5.4 and 1.6.7.

Answer (score 2):

An answer to this question can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/726

In short, where you find mocha.run() (in my case, index.html):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    window.require.list().filter(function (name) {return /test$/.test(name);}).forEach(require);
    mocha.run();
});
</script>
```

This executes all javascript/coffeescript files ending with test, hence register the tests they contain, which mocha.run() will subsequently run.